# regular expression that tests if string is empty

Tags: regex

I am learning about regular expressions and saw this little piece of code that I cannot understand fully. I know what it does since it was explained [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Regular-expressions)

I know the caret, `^` is used to match the beginning of a string.

I know the dollar sign `$` is used to match the end of a string.

How does `/^$/` match an empty string? In my mind it says, "Match the beginning and end of the string." Naturally every string has a beginning and an end. Where does the, "emptiness" come in?

Comment: That is begining of the string immediatly followed by end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does `/^$/` match empty string

- `^` matches the begining
- `$` matches the end of the string.

Since there is nothing betweent the two anchors, the string is empty

Example : http://regex101.com/r/kK9aW2/1

**Note**

when we write a regex `/ab/`

matches an `a` and immediately followed `b`

It doesnt mean that it matches `a` or `b` in the string. It means it matches `ab` in the string

That is the regex matches `abc` and not `acb`

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is the notion of *sequence*.

Just read your regex from left to right: what it really means is not "match the beginning and the end of the string", but "match the beginning of the string, **then** the end of the string".

Since there is nothing in-between, this regex can only accept (= match) empty strings.

(see [nu11p01n73R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27091484/4256882)).

Answer (score 0):

`$` can match the end of string *OR* before a newline.

Example in Perl:  `"\n" =~ /^$/` will also match, but the string is clearly not empty.
In this case it matches before the newline (*last* newline in single line mode) since
the regex makes no allowance to match anything between ^ and $.

Here are some examples and things to watch out for.

```
** String containing single newline \n ..
"\n" =~ /(^$)/ -- matches, $1=''
"\n" =~ /(^\n$)/ -- matches, $1='\n'
"\n" =~ /(^$)(.\z))/s -- matches, $1='', $2='\n'

** Real empty string ..
"" =~ /(^$)/ -- matches, $1=''
"" =~ /(^\z)/ -- matches, $1=''
```